# Django get_cache_key works with database backend but not with filesystem

Tags: python, django, caching, filesystems, django-cache

I'm facing a curious behaviour when trying to use **Django filesystem caching backend**.

When trying to find a per view cache key, I do something like this:

```
request = HttpRequest()
request.path = obj.get_absolute_url()
key = get_cache_key(request)
```

With **database** cache backend, it works like a charm:

```
print key
views.decorators.cache.cache_page..GET.5d9b625d8c44da04c0fc562ad039e0f1.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.fr-fr
```

With **filestem** cache backend:

```
print key
None
```

I checked filesystem cache, and I'm sure the entry actually exists.

Somebody knows how to get it working as well as database caching?

Comment: what does your settings.py contain? does your file cache work at all?

Comment: Hello alex, settings.py contains this cache setting, and it does actually stores cache files on the filesystem: 'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': '/path-to-my-cache',
        'TIMEOUT': 604800
    }

Comment: How do you use cache? The per-view cache?

Comment: Yes I do per-view-cache!

Comment: Does django cache your view?

Comment: Yes, the view is properly cached and delivered by Django. My concern is about expiring the cache for a specific view: I try to get the right cache key and then delete the entry. But with filesystem backend, I can't get the key, which works fine with database caching :(

Comment: Do you use your code inside view function?

Comment: In fact I use it in the save_model method in admin ModelForm.

Comment: Does view call `save_model`?

Comment: Via the request parameter provided by Django: save_model(self, request, obj, form, change)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38970/discussion-between-alexvassel-and-user650108)